# How to calculate the exponentiation of a polynomial with modulo and a residue ring

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, exponentiation

For example,

How to efficiently calculate how much does $(x^3+1)^{40}$ equal to if it is in the field of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^4+x-1)$?

Comment: Replace at will $(a+b)^3$ by $a^3+b^3$ and $x^4$ by $1-x.$

Comment: Hello! May you please edit your question with MathJax and provide the steps and methods you have tried to solve this problem? A guide to MathJax can be found here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: How much do you know about finite fields? Using cyclicity of the multiplicative group leaves only two possibilities for the fortieth power of a non-zero element. If this is an exercise assigned to you, then you should explain that (and other relevant pieces) as [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). For example, if it was given (or proven in an earlier exercise) that $x^4+x-1$ is a so called primitive polynomial, then the efficient way of calculating that power will take one line of text (by yours truly). The need to elaborate makes a huuuuge difference :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has abandoned it.